# get static assets in sinatra's public directory results in 404?

Tags: jquery, json, ruby, sinatra

I'm using the latest minified CDN version of jQuery (3.1.0), and have a json file in my /public directory that I'm attempting to GET and log to console. The three lines in which I do that are:

```
$.getJSON("/public/data.json", function(json) {
  console.log(json);
});
```

This just gives a 404: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

I can add the json to my erb file as a JavaScript object and work from there, but I'd rather it be it's own separate file.

Why am I getting a 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the /public/

It is not necessary.

Public is seen as the top level dir

Comment: Dumb question, but how did you know this?

Comment: This is just Sinatra's default behavior: public assets go in `public/` and they are referenced by a path that _does not include_ `public/`